# Slow performance in MongoDB find command when running from Jest (extremely faster via command line)

Tags: mongodb

I'm running Jest unit test on NestJS application, and noticed that find command takes about 2 seconds.

```
console.time(`Test #${testCount}`)
const cases = await this.casesModel.find({ companyId }).skip(start).limit(pageSize)
console.timeEnd(`Test #${testCount}`)
```

If I run the same command using cli, it takes milliseconds.

The database contains only 300 documents, and each document is about 100 keys.

I checked that companyId key is indexed.

What could be the reason for the big difference in performance ?

Comment: Was the connection to the database already established?  Many drivers don't actually connect until you try to process an operation, to account for that, run the command a few times.

Comment: You are right, I added another call to database and measured the time and it took 400 milliseconds.
Thank you